# Setting multiple initial values in PyQt form

Tags: python, pyqt

I have been trying to create a settings window for an application I'm developing and I want to populate the settings window with either a config file (which I will later write the answers to) or the system defaults if the config file is absent or cannot be opened.

I have seen examples where a few values are populated after the `setupUi(self)` is executed, however I have around 15-20 values and so having 2 huge if statements seems messy. Here is my current state of affairs and I can't figure out how to make it call the function I have created `getConfig`

Is this the best way to populate values? Or is there something else I should try?

```
class SettingsWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_SettingsWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.getConfig(self) #my problem is here
        ... #all the action bindings

    def getConfig(self):
        if not os.path.exists('app.config'):
            self.ui.setDefaults(self) #fallback to defaults if no config file
        with open('app.config') as f:
            self.config = json.load(f)
            ... #bind all the default values
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might put the widgets to be updated in a dictionary where the dictionary key is the value in the config file. The code to update from code is simply read in the values and update from the key.
At the same time, you will be able to access the widget values with ease.
Let me know if this sounds of interest, I will gladly provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a dictionary to store the widgets - see my comment.
Only one EditLine updated but principal is there (Note the label could also be updated in the same way.

```
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):    # any super class is okay
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.settings = {}
        var_label = QtGui.QLabel('Path')
        self.settings['path'] = QtGui.QLineEdit(width=200)
        quitbutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit')
        loadbutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Load Settings')
        savebutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Save Settings')
        layout1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(var_label)
        layout1.addWidget(self.settings['path'])
        layout2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(loadbutton)
        layout2.addWidget(savebutton)
        layout2.addWidget(quitbutton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(layout1)
        layout.addLayout(layout2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        loadbutton.clicked.connect(self.get_config)
        savebutton.clicked.connect(self.save_settings)
        quitbutton.clicked.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        self.get_config()


    def get_config(self):
        # Read config file here into dictionary
        # Example
        config_data = {'path':'data path here'} # Example dictionary created when reading config file
        for key in config_data:
            self.settings[key].setText(config_data[key])

    def save_settings(self): # Link to button
        data = {}
        for key in self.settings:
            data[key] = self.settings[key].text()
        # Save to config file here
        print (data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If the widgets you use are not set by setText() or retrieved by text() then the code is a little more complex, various ways of doing that for TextEdit, Lists, Combo etc. can be incorporated.

Comment: The dictionary approach helps, but if I understand correctly you have bound the configuration loading to a button which must be pressed. Is there any way to get it to load automatically upon opening the window so that the user doesn't have to press a button? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just call the function at the end of the __init__ method
I have edited my suggested answer.
self.get_config()

Comment: I just realized I had a different error which was hampering my progress. But everything you described worked, the dictionary part was very useful! Thanks